# PHP genera error al intentar usar las propiedades de la clase ¿Por qué?

Tags: php

estoy haciendo una clase usando PHP, intento inicializarla usando la función constructora `function __construct(){}`, definiendo valores iniciales a dos propiedades que se encuentran en la clase, una de esas clases es un arreglo, uso la función `array_push` pero se genera el siguiente error:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: array_push(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in /var/www/feraaam/services/x/SSMS-Wrapper.php:10\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/feraaam/services/x/SSMS-Wrapper.php(10): array_push()\n#1 /var/www/feraaam/lib/fn/post.php(46): Test->addElement()\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/feraaam/services/x/SSMS-Wrapper.php on line 10`

A continuación pongo la clase:

```
class Test{
    function __construct($_text, $data=[]){
        $this->$text = $_text;
        $this->$elements = $data;
    }
    public function addElement($str){
        var_dump($this->$elements);
        array_push($this->elements, $str);
    }
    public function getElements(){
        return $this->$elements;
    }
    public function getElementsAsString(){
        $index = 0;
        $string = '';
        while(isset($this->$elements[$index])){
            $string .= $this->$elements[$index].'\n\r';
            $index++;
        }
        return $this->$elements;
    }
}
```

También la hecho de la siguiente manera:

```
class Test{
    public $text;
    public $elements;
    function __construct($_text, $data=[]){
        $this->$text = $_text;
        $this->$elements = $data;
    }
    public function addElement($str){
        var_dump($this->$elements);
        array_push($this->elements, $str);
    }
    public function getElements(){
        return $this->$elements;
    }
    public function getElementsAsString(){
        $index = 0;
        $string = '';
        while(isset($this->$elements[$index])){
            $string .= $this->$elements[$index].'\n\r';
            $index++;
        }
        return $this->$elements;
    }
}
```

Cuando intento usar la clase lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
$TestObject = new Test('http://localhost/', ['Un elemento']);
$TestObject->addElement('Un texto de prueba.');
```

En la definición de la clase uso la función `var_dump` con la propiedad `$this->$elements`, el cual es un arreglo y así es como se muestra en la salida que da PHP; así:

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
string(11) "Un elemento"
}
```

Inmediatamente después se ejecuta la función `array_push` y se genera el error, realmente no entiendo por qué se genera dicho error.
¿Será que alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Comment: En tu segunda clase, cambia las referencias de $this->$elements A $this->elements, no hace falta colocar el carácter $, el carácter sólo es necesario en la declaración de la variable(propiedad, atributo)

Comment: Excelente... Muchas Gracias!!